# Get DB query log on page load

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3, magento2.2, magento2.1

Currently, our Magento 2.3.4 speed is so slow.
With the homepage, it takes 5 secs to load with 200 MySQL queries running.
But with the category, it takes 20 secs and nearly 3000 queries.
Can you please let me know how to log the MySQL queries on the category page load?

Comment: You could use the General Log to track from before Category page start until Category page completed, get SHOW FULL PROCESS LIST; during the Category page 20 seconds to identify the PID that delivered the Category page data.  Be sure to turn General Log=0; as soon as possible.  General Log will cause extended run time for deliver the Category page data.  Here is a helpful URL related to General Log - https://riptutorial.com/mysql/example/18052/general-query-log - you may have to compensate for Linux OS.  Concept is the same.

Comment: View my profile, Network profile for free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.